# UITableViewCell Animation inside custom cell. But animated with Another cells UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

UITableViewCell Animation inside custom cell. But animated with Another cells UIView.

Hi, Now I make simple tableview with custom cell.
And I want Animation inside custom cell.
This Animation is very simple, when push "Green" button, change from Orange slide to Green.
when push "Orange" button, change form Green slide to Orange.
But my program is moved with another UIView, I tried another logics, But I don't have right CODE. Please Help me.
This is my code, and use with Storyboard.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy8kk19k2a4cb6d/CellTest.zip

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForControlEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
return indexPath;

}

- (IBAction)greenPush:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForControlEvent:event];

UITableViewCell *cell_1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *greenViewTest = (UIView *)[cell_1 viewWithTag:2];
UIView *orangeViewTest = (UIView *)[cell_1 viewWithTag:1];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[orangeViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 10, 300, 300)];
[greenViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)orangePush:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForControlEvent:event];
UITableViewCell *cell_2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *greenViewTest = (UIView *)[cell_2 viewWithTag:2];
UIView *orangeViewTest = (UIView *)[cell_2 viewWithTag:1];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[orangeViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300)];
[greenViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(-300, 10, 300, 300)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

return cell;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: check by putting a breakpoint, whether it is returning the correct indexpath or not.I guess it is returning indexPath of next row cell.hence the weird behaviour.

Comment: Now I tried.  Default indexPath is No problem, But, still display cell is problem when if use "IBAction". For example, Displayed 7 cell, hiding 8th cells indexPath be 0. But, I do not know how to solve, this problem. (Sorry my English is not good) Thanks Santhu

Comment: what do you mean by hiding 8th cell? And what is the exact behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: Can you try this one?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy8kk19k2a4cb6d/CellTest.zip

Comment: I added this CODE.
But can not keep Moved Animations.

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIView *greenViewTest = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIView *orangeViewTest = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    
    [orangeViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
    [greenViewTest setFrame:CGRectMake(-300, 10, 20, 20)];
    
    }`

Comment: I understood this problem. maybe this problem is Asynchronous of UITableViewCell. But I don't have idea that How can I do to solve.

Comment: I already solved. Thanks all
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs1j21t94go78b6/CellTest_new.zip